# CreateFolder element not creating correct directory

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm building an installer for one of my programs. I need to create an empty folder named `logs`.

I've tried the following in my wxs file, following instructions that say to use the `CreateFolder` element inside of a component (GUIDs have been removed from this post):

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
  <Directory Id='UserFolder' Name='UFolder'>
    <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='SH Analysis'>
      <Directory Id='logDIR' Name='logs'>
        <Component Id='CreateLogDir' Guid='...' SharedDllRefCount='no' KeyPath='no' NeverOverwrite='no' Permanent='no' Transitive='no' Win64='no' Location='either'>
          <CreateFolder />
        </Component>
      </Directory>

    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

<Feature Id='Complete' Level='1'>
  <ComponentRef Id='CreateLogDir' />
</Feature>
```

The program compiles and links without warnings or errors, and the .msi runs without issues, but the `logs` folder isn't being created. Is there something I've missed?

Comment: Not sure if you actually installed the compiled MSI file. Did you install it? If this is in the user profile I would have your application create the folder on demand instead.

Comment: Yes I should clarify, I ran the generated msi without issues as well. The root directory was created but without the internal logs folder.

Comment: I might just go ahead and change the program so it's generated by the application instead of the installer. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes, maybe try that. Your installer can't clean out folders for all users anyway. I leave everything in the user profile as it is - not touching anything in order to avoid disasters. You can have the MSI delete the folder in the user profile if you insist - though, but keep it simple. My 2 cents :-). Much easier to debug EXE file launch code than setup code.

Comment: Very true, thank you once again.

Comment: No problem, I should clarify that you can delete a user profile folder via your MSI only for the user uninstalling the MSI. In other words not for all users (unless you implement some seriously involved logic - which you should not do - the user profile is user data, do not uninstall haphazardly).